# Extending Python with parallelized C programs (under OMP)

Tags: python, c, parallel-processing, openmp

So, I am considering to make a C extension of a python component that I've got. Then, I thought of using OMP to take as much advantage as I can from the machines that will, eventually, run the combined solution of Python+C.

Has anyone tried something similar at all? Are there any particular, unpropitious, details than could make such a solution fail?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done this successfully for large data mining tasks in radio astronomy. See https://github.com/ewanbarr/sigpyproc.git for an example.

The thing to note is that the C libraries I built in these cases are accessed via ctypes and not as native Python extensions.

So, for example:

Python: test.py

```
import ctypes as C
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import as_ctypes
lib = C.CDLL("libmytest.so")

def set_N_threads(nthreads):
    self.lib.omp_set_num_threads(nthreads)

def do_some_task(input_array):
    input_array = input_array.astype("float32")
    output_array = np.empty_like(input_array)
    lib.do_some_omp_task(as_ctypes(input_array),
                         as_ctypes(output_array),
                         C.c_size_t(input_array.size))
    return output_array
```

C: test.c

```
#include <omp.h>

void do_some_omp_task(float* input_array,
                      float* output_array,
                      size_t size)
{
   int ii;
#pragma omp parallel for default(shared) private(ii)
   for (ii=0;ii<size;ii++)
       do something using ii and the arrays
}
```

Compile:

```
gcc -O3 -lm -fopenmp -fPIC -c test.c -o test.o
gcc -shared -lgomp -o libmytest.so test.o
```

To answer your question, I have had no problems with this kind of setup and the speed improvements achievable have been impressive (although the above example wouldn't really benefit from OMP)

Comment: Very promising! Thank you very much! I was specially concerned about the thread safety of function calls and how that could affect the python side of things. But from what I see in your example, the interfacing doesn't leave much room for things to go wrong, from a thread level perspective. I'll look into it as of now! Thanks again.

Comment: When using ctypes, as long as the library is not called using PyDLL, the Global Interpreter Lock is released, so the C functions and their threads act independently of Python.

Answer (score 3):

[Cython](http://cython.org) has `parallel.prange()`, [example](https://gist.github.com/3733763#file-b2a_bin-pyx).

To do it manually, call `PyEval_InitThreads` on your extension module initialization. Release GIL while forking non-python threads e.g., by wrapping OMP parallel section in `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS/Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS`. Acquire/release GIL if you need access to python objects using `state = PyGILState_Ensure()/PyGILState_Release(state)`. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/3471699#file-c_extension_module-c) (convoluted to trigger an error in threading module on shutdown). To avoid any issues, import `threading` on your module initialization.

Comment: The solution from @ebarr came quite handy, so I took that approach. However this definitely seems be most useful as well. Since I like to do things in various ways, I'll keep this in mind! Thank you very much for your time.